# How to remove action from within a singleton class

Tags: php, wordpress, singleton

I am trying to remove an action from a plugin via my child theme functions.php. The function is wrapped in a singleton class. I tried with this

```
function remove_wc_monarch(){
    global $ET_Monarch;
    $ET_Monarch = new ET_Monarch();

remove_action( 'woocommerce_after_single_product_summary', array( $ET_Monarch, 'display_on_wc_page' ), 999 );

}

add_action('init', 'remove_wc_monarch');
```

But that render a dead page with this message *ET_Monarch is a singleton class and you cannot create a second instance.*

This is how the class was initiated

```
class ET_Monarch {
    var $plugin_version = '1.2.7.2';
    var $db_version = '1.2';
    var $monarch_options;
    var $_options_pagename = 'et_monarch_options';
    var $menu_page;
    var $protocol;

    public static $shortcodes_count = 0;
    public static $total_follows_count = '';
    public static $follow_counts_array = '';

    private static $_this;

    function __construct() {
        // Don't allow more than one instance of the class
        if ( isset( self::$_this ) ) {
            wp_die( sprintf( esc_html__( '%s is a singleton class and you cannot create a second instance.', 'Monarch' ),
                get_class( $this ) )
            );
        }

        self::$_this = $this;
```

Comment: Is there a way to get a reference to the singleton instance? Maybe something like `ET_Monarch::getInstance()` or maybe some other object can give you the instance.

Answer (score 1):

Monarch plugin have the static function get_this().

I am using this with my hooks in genesis and works fine.

regards